# Incorrect removal of a child object in jquery

Tags: jquery

I would love to start off by saying that I am no expert in JQuery yet, and I know I am doing something wrong here.

The issue is, when I remove a child from an element, it only empties the child and leaves it hanging in the parent node:

The code:

```
function DeleteAttributeFromNr(id) {
    $("#tbodyAttributes").children("#row-" + id).remove();

    CheckAttributes();
}

function CheckAttributes() {
    if ($("#tbodyAttributes tr").length <= 1) {
        $("#tbAttributes tbody").append('<tr><td colspan="3" id="tdEmptyBody">You have no attributes assigned to this number yet.</td></tr>');
    } else if ($("#tdEmptyBody").length == 1) {
        $("#tdEmptyBody").remove();
    }
}
```

the result after a couple of removals out of `"#tbodyAttributes tr"`

```
<tbody id="tbodyAttributes">
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
</tbody>
```

This is a fair screwup for my logical code in CheckAttributes as you may notice. Is there other ways of removing the `<tr>` as a whole?

I have tried:

```
$("#tbodyAttributes").removeChild("#row-" + id); //Very surprised this did not exist
$("#tbodyAttributes").children("#row-" + id).remove();
$("#tbodyAttributes").find("#row-" + id).remove();
$("#row-" + id).remove();
$("#row-" + id).empty(); //desperation run, I knew this one would not work since I use it a lot to clear out tables
```

I know its something obvious. I did scout the *whackystacky* but no answers came to my rescue (of which I could find)

Comment: will try. gonna try and set it up on jsfiddle quick

Comment: Well, you should remove .parent()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. I had a brain fade.

I was busy removing the `<td colspan="3" id="tdEmptyBody">You have no attributes assigned to this number yet.</td>`, which is not a `<tr>`, but the child of the tr tag.  This means **the empty tr tag will remain unless I remove tr:empty along with tdEmptyBody**

The solution:

```
 $("#tbAttributes tbody").append('<tr id="trEmptyBody"><td colspan="3" >You have no attributes assigned to this number yet.</td></tr>');
```

I had to rename the tr element here to trEmptyBody, and update my code references to this.

```
        if ($("#tbodyAttributes tr").length <= 1) {
            $("#tbAttributes tbody").append('<tr id="trEmptyBody"><td colspan="3" >You have no attributes assigned to this number yet.</td></tr>');
        } else if ($("#trEmptyBody").length == 1) {
            $("#tbAttributes #trEmptyBody").remove();
        }
```

My code works now. Apologies for wasting everyone's time

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function CheckAttributes() {
    if ($("#tbodyAttributes tr").length <= 1) {
        $("#tbAttributes tbody").append('<tr><td colspan="3" id="tdEmptyBody">You have no attributes assigned to this number yet.</td></tr>');
    } else if ($("#tdEmptyBody").length == 1) {

        // $("#tdEmptyBody").remove();  This just remove the td only
        $("#tdEmptyBody").closest('tr').remove();
    }
}
```

and to remove empty `tr`

```
$("#tbodyAttributes > tr:empty").remove();
```

Comment: 5 points to griffindor. Your answer made me insta-spot my mistake. Your method would have worked too.